# Dynamic @font-face in ng-style

Tags: css, angularjs, font-face

I have specifics fonts that will be tied to user layouts. When a user logs in, they will see their selected fonts which will be loaded from the server.
I will be using Angular to style the specific elements. How can I use @font-face in ng-style? Is it possible?

font-family works if I type all the possible font-faces prior which is tedious and hard to maintain. the CSS is the section I want to load dynamically based on the user's fonts

```
**CSS** 

@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFontName;
    src: url('CustomFont.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: CustomFontName2;
    src: url('CustomFont2.ttf');
}

**JS**

textbox.style = {
  'font-family': CustomFontName
}

**HTML**

<p ng-style="textbox.style">{{ textbox.placeholder }}</p>
```

The website is [here](http://new.nameprintgraphics.com), you can test it out with validation code "ImprintPlus" and then change templates. the user will want their customized fonts in there.

Comment: One way to go would be to add a custom web component that would include the necessary `<style>` tag. But this could also be achieved using DOM's [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

Comment: Yes, should be possible. [ngStyle]="{'font-family': userSelectedFont.customFontName}"